# JUNIT How to check the custom object retrieved is sorted in assertthat

Tags: java, junit

Hi I am using Hibernate to retreive the element in sorted order FindByOrderByValueAsc.

How to check it is sorted in Junit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `Comparator` for the fields that you are interested in.

```
Comparator<YourObject> cmp = 
Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getOrder)
          .thenComparing(YourObject::getValue);

for(int i = 0; i < yourResult.size() - 1; ++i) {
    YourObject left = yourResult.get(i);
    YourObject right = yourResult.get(i + 1);
    if(cmp.compare(left, right) > 0) {
        Assert.fail("not sorted")
    }
}
```

have not compiled, obviously, any of this code.

Comment: Works fine.. Just it checks in descending order. changed to greater than symbol.

Comment: @sathishkumar in such a case you can aceept the answer.

Comment: How to do the same in Mockito?

Comment: @sathishkumar ask a clear, separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have the retrieved elements in a `List<SomeType>`.

Write a method that will iterate a `List<T>` using a `Comparator<T>` to compare successive elements, and return false if a pair is out of order.

Write the assertion to call the method on the retrieved elements with an appropriate `Comparator<SomeType>`.  Fail the assertion if the call returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

There are assertion libraries that can be used with JUnit that have more sophisticated assertions than JUnit itself. E.g. with [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) you can write

```
assertThat(theList).containsExactly(firstValue, secondValue)
```